# Finding the domain of a function (that is described by a DE) such that the function is real

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following DE:

$$n\cdot y(x)^2=\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}$$

How can I find the domain of $x$ such that $y:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (so that the solution is real-valued) in terms of $n$ (which is a real positive number) and the initial condition $y(a)=b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers)?

Comment: What about solving the ODEs $y^\prime(x) =\pm\sqrt{1-n y^2(x)}$ and looking at the maximal intervals where solutions are defined?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I do not know how to do that. Can you help me with that?

Comment: See additional elements in the answer below.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Where is the answer?

Comment: Deleted for the time being as I made an error.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net okay, I am looking forward to your answer

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice that if $y$ is a solution of the given ODE, so is $-y$. Therefore, we can without loss of generality suppose that $y(a) >0$.

Suppose that $y^\prime(a) >0$. You can deal with the other alternative in a similar way.

You have

$$y^\prime(x) =\sqrt{n^2 y^4(x) - 1}$$ which implies the condition $\vert y(a) \vert \gt 1/ \sqrt n$. Locally around $a$

$$x-a = \int_a^x \frac{y^\prime(x)}{\sqrt{n^2y^4(x) -1}} \ dx= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{y(a)}^{y(x)} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^4-1/n^2}}.$$

The integral

$$I(b,n)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{b}^\infty \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^4-1/n^2}}$$ is convergent. And the solution $y$ is defined  on the right on the interval
$(a, a + I(b,n))$. *Not sure that there is a closed value for $I(b,n)$ though.*